# How to get client IP using Mosquitto MQTT

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I would like to log the IP address of clients using Mosquitto MQTT. I am using Paho - Python on the server side and Arduino - PubSubClient on the client side.

In PHP, it is quite simple, I just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Is there something similar for Mosquitto?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information? Is it just for debugging/diagnosis? Or are you trying to connect back to clients on another protocol?

Comment: @njh I'm going to keep in in case I find abuse of the system, then I can flag the IP. I am concerned about this because the Arduino can't encrypt the messages, so someone could sniff the data and spoof a unit

Comment: Like with any  IP-flagging system, I am afraid you will be flagging all the terminals behind the routers/ NAT system you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @njh: one of the uses I have right away is that I get in the logs `Client <unknown> closed its connection.` and I would like to match this to the IP of that client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mosquitto records when new clients connect if logging is enabled:

```
Oct 13 15:09:32 bagend mosquitto[1361]: 1476367772: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
Oct 13 15:09:32 bagend mosquitto[1361]: 1476367772: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mosqsub/18943-bagend (c1, k60).
```

This shows a new client connecting from localhost and includes the client id `mosqsub/18943-bagend`

There is no way to get it from another MQTT client as every client has no knowledge of any other clients connected to the broker.

EDIT: The mosquitto.conf man page implies you may be able to log to a MQTT topic using the following in the config file:

```
log_dest topic
```

This logs to a topic of `$SYS/broker/log/<log level>`

so you get something like this when subscribing with `mosquitto_sub -v -t '$SYS/broker/log/#'`

```
$SYS/broker/log/N 1476378785: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1885.
$SYS/broker/log/N 1476378785: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mosqpub/4654-tiefighter (c1, k60).
$SYS/broker/log/N 1476378785: Client mosqpub/4654-tiefighter disconnected.
```

Comment: is there a way to scrape this ip from the connect message and bring it into Paho?

Comment: You can always parse logs, but that would be a separate question. I've updated the answer after remembering something

Answer (score 0):

I just set the IP as the client ID. Be careful with this though. If anyone has taken up this client ID already, you will get disconnected with reason code 1.

Alternatively, you can use the user data field.